# sentiment analysis and efficient clustering of raw text with minimal context

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark, nlp

Say I have an email chain where 2 people discuss about a problem and its solution. I have some context too. Example, the email chain is about some problem in using iPhone 6 with iOS 7. Thats it. From the content/text of these emails, I need to figure out what exactly the problem is and what exactly is the solution proposed.

Now, if we port this problem to big data i.e. millions of such email chains, I want to know how to classify or cluster them.

I am using Apache Spark's MLlib - LDA, FPgrowth and Kmeans (+ a huge list of stop words). But my results dont look correct. Playing around with params for these algorithms is just giving me knowledge but not good results. My biggest problem is not having training data. Unfortunately, most solutions I see online use manually created training data. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/). You can use it to create word vectors or sentence vectors. And also do k-means clustering on top of them.

If you are looking for noisy text datasets, you can check out

- [Ubuntu Chat Corpus](http://daviduthus.org/UCC/)
- [Enron e-mail dataset](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/)